# How to select all immediate children for a :not()

Tags: jquery

If I have the following html, how do I use Jquery to only select the first level children and apply :not to them

```
<div id="top">
    <span>select me</span>
    <a>select me</a>
    <div>
        <span>not this</span>
        <a>not this</a>
    </div>
    <div class="not-this">not this</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#top>:not(.not-this)'); // errors due to the >
jQuery('#top:not(.not-this)');  // selects the second level children.
```

It needs to be agnostic of the tags used for the children.

Edit to add: Also tried

```
jQuery('#top>*:not(.not-this)');  // selects the second level children.
```

Comment: What version of jquery and what "error" do you get with the `>`?  None of the results you are claiming should work as you state.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I just retried and it didn't error, but it still does not do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery('#top>:not(.not-this)')` should actually work just fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/Entxc/

Another alternative is this:

```
$("#top").children().not(".not-this")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Entxc/1/

Comment: Your fiddle is selecting the children, I don't want it too.

Comment: You specifically say you want it to select the first level children.  That is what this does.

Comment: The problem is it also selects the second level children - they have the border. I only want the first level children.

Comment: This is not selecting 2nd level children.  If it was, it would look like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Entxc/2/   I think you may need to re-word what you are asking for because this matches what you have asked.

Comment: I want it too look like this http://jsfiddle.net/Entxc/3/ but be agnostic of the tags used.

Comment: So then you want only first level children which do not have any children of their own.  That is different.

Comment: Ahh, yes sorry. You were right all along. For some reason it is not working in my code. The bug must be elsewhere - perhaps the code is being applied to the children in a separate process. Thanks for your help.